# Multi Tenancy - Register JNDI datasources dynamically

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, multi-tenant

I would like to know how to register JNDI datasources dynamically with the multi-tenant-core-plugin in the single-tenant mode. I searched for nearly two weeks and found some hints how to do it, like the JndiTemplate or the BeanBuilder. But I wasn't able to figure it out ..
I would appreciate if someone could help me..

Some information to this:
Grails 1.3.7,
Hibernate 1.3.7
Tomcat 1.3.7
Multi-tenant-core plugin 1.0.0

It would be really nice to register a customer with his own datasource on the fly without stopping the program and adding him in the grails.naming.entries and in the DatasourceTenantMap... I know that there is a domain class DataSourceTenantMap.groovy :

```
class DataSourceTenantMap {
   String dataSource
   Integer mappedTenantId

   static constraints = {}
}
```

but I have to register more than just the mappedTenantId and the datasource. Therefore I tried to bind a BasicDataSource with JndiTemplate or the NamingManager. But it hadn't worked..

If more information are needed, please ask for them!

Comment: Hi there,

Has anybody got any ideas? Would be great if someone could give some insights... 

Cheers, Mel

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer as I can't figure out how to do a comment. (meaning, I don't see an "Add comment" link, above).

I have had the same issue with Grails 2.0.3

See: [Grails 2 multiple dynamic datasources in services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857663/grails-2-multiple-dynamic-datasources-in-services)

I am perhaps a little further ahead, because I am injecting the datasource bean - ie, I have exactly the same scenario - but it's not getting picked up by Grails.

The problem is universal and I was hoping somebody on the grails team with insight would answer:

Multitenant Application running as a service should allow for addition of another tenant at runtime. That means, if I want to tell the app that there's a brand new tenant database that it should use, I should be able to do that at runtime, instead of bouncing the app.