# Grails 2 multiple dynamic datasources in services

Tags: grails, datasource

I am working on a Grails application where I must access several datasources. The datasources are defined in the default database (ie. they are stored there and I must make a call to the default database to retrieve a list of the datasource names I must prepare to connect to). When the server boots up I retrieve the list of databases, create the datasource beans and inject them. All dynamically added databases are structurally identical (ie. have the same table and domain object structure).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534238/grails-2-how-to-dynamically-call-multiple-datasources) is the closest I got to a useful piece of code, but it's not quite what I need.

#### Issue #1

- When I register the datasource beans, they show up where I expect, but Grails does not pick them up.

This is how I add them:

```
// Register datasource bean
def beanName = 'dataSource_devDB1'

BeanBuilder bb = new BeanBuilder()
bb.beans {
    "${beanName}"(BasicDataSource) { 
        url = "jdbc:h2:devDB1Db;MVCC=TRUE"
        pooled = true
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        username = "sa"
        password = ""            
    }
}

bb.registerBeans(grailsApplication.mainContext)

// check that it registered
def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext
def ctxlist = ctx2.beanDefinitionNames.findAll{it.contains( 'dataSource' )}

log.info "ctxlist = " + ctxlist
```

This prints:

```
[dataSource, dataSourceUnproxied, dataSource_devDB1]
```

When I do this, I can execute operations on the default datasource, and that's it.

#### Issue #2

- If I declare all my datasources as part of the `Datasource.groovy` file, then I can execute operations on all my databases, but not [as advertised by the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources)

It works if I do the static mapping on my domain objects:

```
static mapping = {datasources(['devDB1', 'devDB2', 'DEFAULT')] or datasource = 'ALL'
```

but what I want is to perform all this as part of a service, and declaring my domain objects to use ALL datasources.

Declaring the datasource in the service is not working:

```
class secureDBService{

  static datasource = "devDB1"

  def readWriteMethod(){
   .....
  // this always uses the default datasource ignoring the static property above.
  // the only time it uses devDB1 is if I declare it as part of the domain datasource
  // mapping
  }
}
```

This will always use the default datasource no matter what. The only time when it uses the correct datasource is if on the domain object I list the datasource in question.

---

So, has anyone:

1. tried adding dynamic datasources and succeeded?
2. switched between datasources using grails services?
3. (and this would be a fantastic extra , as a "cherry on top") had success using multiple datasource with spring security core? How do you switch the datasource for the security plugin?

Thanks

--

Comment: At this point I will almost settle for anyone telling me they have successfully ran Grails in multi-tenant (multiple datasource) mode using Grails services to decide the DB. Anyone? If yes, how?

Comment: http://springandgrailsmusings.blogspot.ca/2011/02/registering-new-bean-classes-in-grails.html

Comment: I also need assistance with a scenario very similar to this.

Comment: @Kyle Were you able to solve this problem of switching datasources in grails services?

Comment: Hello, Trying to clean up unanswered. Did you solve this? Maybe you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 3):

I've got two different datasources working with Grails 2.3.11. I'm using 1 datasource for my H2 database and another for an Oracle db. I had to use Hibernate 4 with Grails 2.3. In my `BuildConfig.groovy` I specified the dependency on hibernate 4:

```
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4"
```

In my `DataSource.groovy` file I used the following Hibernate caching settings:

```
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory'
    singleSession = true // configure OSIV singleSession mode
}
```

(SIDE NOTE: without the cache settings, I was getting following CacheManager error, "Another unnamed CacheManager already exists in the same VM". There's an open bug report on this at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPCACHEEHCACHE-13, but once I put the settings in place the error was gone.)

then I defined my datasources:

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource_oracle {
            pooled = true
            dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
            driverClassName = 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
            username = 'user'
            password = 'pass'
            url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@(serverName):(port):(SID)'
            dbCreate = 'validate'
        }
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
               jmxEnabled = true
               initialSize = 5
               maxActive = 50
               minIdle = 5
               maxIdle = 25
               maxWait = 10000
               maxAge = 10 * 60000
               timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
               minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
               validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
               validationQueryTimeout = 3
               validationInterval = 15000
               testOnBorrow = true
               testWhileIdle = true
               testOnReturn = false
               jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
               defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By default, my Domain classes use the H2 db and I specify my Oracle datasource as:

```
class MyService {

    def dataSource_oracle
    static transactional = true

    def getMethod() {
        assert dataSource_oracle != null, "dataSource is null! Please check your configuration!"
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(dataSource_oracle)
        ...
    }
}
```

Above, I allow the dependency injection to provide the service with the oracle datasource, `def dataSource_oracle`. If I want to use the H2 datasource, I declare the datasource as `def dataSource` and allow the DI to inject my other datasource.

---

**I could not get the two datasources to work as specified in the documentation** at http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.11/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources. By declaring the datasources as dataSource and dataSource_lookup then using it as:

```
class DataService {
   static datasource = 'lookup'

   void someMethod(...) {
      …
   }
}
```

but **I was able to get it working with the solution described above**.

---

Answer (score 1):

I worked on similar project where the application has to retrieve list of datasources (connection strings) from the default database, and connect to each datasource and perform operations using quartz jobs.

I implemented it like, connect to each datasource within the application (not from *DataSorce.groovy*) and write SQL rather tahn HQL.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class SqlService{
    Sql getDbConnection(String connectionString, String dbUser, String dbPassword){
        def sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionString, dbUser, dbPassword, "driver_class")
        return sql
    }
}
```

Get `sql` connection from the above code and execute SQL queries using `sql.execute "SQL STATEMENT"` and close the `sql` connection. [Here](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) is the `Sql` class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple data sources in a single application, and access them in the services.

Firstly you need to add basic data sources in the resources.groovy.

first import BasicDataSource

```
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
```

Then

```
    switch (grails.util.GrailsUtil.environment) {
    case "development":
        firstDataSource( BasicDataSource ) {
            driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=<Db_name>"
            username = "sa"
            password = "root"
            String SqlServerInstance = "SQLEXPRESS";
            url = url + ";" + SqlServerInstance;
        }
        break

    case "test":
        firstDataSource( BasicDataSource ) {

            driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=<Db_name>"
            username = "sa"
            password = "root"
            String SqlServerInstance = "SQLEXPRESS";
            url = url + ";" + SqlServerInstance;            }
        break;

}
```

In the same way you can add more data sources, above code will give you one more datasource to access other than the default one.
I used switch to configure same data source for the different environments, same way more can be added.

and in the service it can be accessed in the services as:

```
BasicDataSource firstDataSource;
Connection con = firstDataSource.getConnection();
```

and then connection object can be used.

I think it should help

Comment: This doesn't help answer the original question.  He needs to create dataSource beans dynamically from another database connection, not a flat file.  I'm having the same issue.  It doesn't seem like Grails has a nice "friendly" way of reboostrapping domain classes with the main context dataSource beans.  I hope someone can answer our questions.

Comment: hmm may be..I thought it may help.. because posting it all in comments would not be appropriate..

Answer (score 0):

Use sharding plugin for grails that will address your issue