# Grails datasource becoming null in Service

Tags: grails, service, null, datasource

I am using Grails 2.2.1, and I have a custom dataSource injected into the service so that I can execute some SQL queries.

Upon first execution, there is a dataSource, but on each subsequent call, the reference to the dataSource has become null.

```
class ReportService {
  def dataSource_myds

  Object[] reportRecords(int a) {
    String query = "SELECT ..."

    Object[] resultSet;

    Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource_myds)
    // ^ Here the NullPointerException is thrown
    // But it always works at the first execution

    sql.eachRow(query, [a]) {
      ...
      resultSet += result
    }
    return resultSet
  }
}

class ReportController {
  ReportService reportService

  def report = {
     ...
     Object[] resultSet1 = reportService.reportRecords(1)
     ...
     Object[] resultSet2 = reportService.reportRecords(2)
     // ^ java.lang.NullPointerException : Must specify a non-null Connection
     ...
  }
}
```

Has anyone ever seen this before, and if so, how can I avoid this?

Here is my DataSource.groovy

```
environments {
  development {
    dataSource_myds {
      url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@..."
      driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      username = "..."
      password = "..."
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `sql.close()` after the `sql.eachRow()` method.

Comment: ReportService reportService in ReportController should be def reportService might not affect your use case.

Comment: @AnujAneja I don't think there is anything wrong with strictly typed fields.

Comment: @micha: Yes, you are right!!!

Comment: Run `grails clean` and restart your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try, to use resources.groovy way as well. This will also give you option for environment basis datasource.

Explained well on the link given below:

[Grails 2 multiple dynamic datasources in services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857663/grails-2-multiple-dynamic-datasources-in-services?rq=1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved avoiding 2 subsequent calls to the service. It seems the framework nulls the service connection after the first call from the controller.

Comment: I have the same problem - if I understand your note here, you just worked around it by not doing 2 subsequent calls? So really not a solution to the original problem? I'm hoping to find a full solution.

Comment: Yes, it was a workaround; I did not found a full solution and I still don't understand how the Service dependency injection works on subsequent calls.

Comment: See my answer of Sept 21 and James Kleeh's comment to your question for the full solution.

Answer (score 1):

James Kleeh's comment solved it for me - `grails clean` and then restart the app.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I got it fixed. Firstly, make sure your Service class is in the `grails-app/services` folder. Secondly, you need to make sure you get the object of the service class using the injection mechanism and not by using the constructor. I had my service class in the right folder but I was trying to create the instance of the service class as `MyService.instance` in my controller and having the issue of null dataSource/connection. Then I tried `def myService` in my controller instead of `MyService.instance` and it worked. Hope this helps. Thanks