# dataSource is getting null after first call

Tags: grails

when i do first call from controller to service class i am able to access dataSource but in second call dataSource is getting null. would you please share ideas how to fix that issue. i am putting sample code here

```
//controller class
class atulController 
{
  def databaseService
  def callinsert(){
      databaseService.insert();
    }
}

//Service class
class databaseService {
  def dataSource
  def insert(){
     def sql = new Sql(dataSource);
  }
}
```

Comment: Bad nomenclature for class names. Has to be `AtulContoller` and `DatabaseService` instead.

Comment: Exact same question seems to have been asked on Sept 4 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620448/grails-datasource-becoming-null-in-service

Answer (score 0):

Read about the service [scope](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Services/scope.html). By default it's singleton (so it should work with any call to service), but in your case it may be of another scope. Make sure it's signleton.